# Determining stack size at runtime in a C++ Program

Tags: c++, stack, runtime, c++14

I would like to know if there is a way to programmatically determine the stack size of a running program in C++. If so, is there also a way to programatically determine how much heap memory the program is using at run time? For determining the size of the heap, I could see a potential way by overloading the `new` and `delete` operator, but I don't think this would work with smart pointers.

I tried to achieve it with the following:

```
int main(){
    const char STACK_BEGIN = 'A';
    //a lot of code
    register unsigned long int STACK_NOW asm("%esp");
    long long int stack_size = (reinterpret_cast<int>(&STACK_BEGIN) - STACK_NOW);
    //rest of code
}
```

Comment: No, there are not really standard methods to do so. There may be OS specific system calls to get that information though.

Comment: As I recall in Windows stack pages are only committed as needed. That means that the cost of specifying a large stack is only somewhat reduced address space, not actual memory use (until needed, that is). Anyway, by using standard collections such as `std::vector` that allocate their buffers dynamically, you can reduce stack usage significantly.

Comment: I would think you could get at least an approximate idea of stack usage by storing a globally accessible pointer to the first variable you declare on the stack in your `main()` routine, and then at any time during the execution of your program, find the difference between the address of a recently declared stack variable and the value of that global pointer. It's a crude technique but should offer at least an idea of stack usage.

Answer (score 2):

I approximately solved it like this:

```
int main(){ 
    const char STACK_BEGIN = 'A'; //a lot of code 
    register unsigned long int STACK_NOW asm("%esp"); 
    long long int stack_size = (reinterpret_cast<int>(&STACK_BEGIN) - STACK_NOW); //rest of code 
}
```

Comment: Any idea why you have to use x86 asm rather than declaring a second char on the stack and taking its address just like you do with STACK_BEGIN ?

Comment: This determines the size stack you have used after "//a lot of code". Don't see, how this is delivering the available stack size.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the stack is an attribute of a thread, each thread has it's own stack.
As threads are provided by the platform, the system interface may or may not provide the information.
For Linux this is function `pthread_attr_getstacksize()`.

If in addition you want to get the actual address range, you get this from STACK_BEGIN and the processor architectural convention, that stacks are top-down, i.e. STACK_BEGIN is actually at the top and the bottom is about at `STACK_BEGIN-´size of the stack´`.

For Windows the stack range is hidden in `GetThreadInformation(()`, see [processhacker](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntpsapi.h)

**EDIT** According to comment from Raymond Chen [GetCurrentThreadStackLimits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthreadstacklimits) is the documented choice inside Windows SDK.

Comment: No need to call undocumented APIs when there's the documented function [GetCurrentThreadStackLimits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthreadstacklimits).